# JPA - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [productName] is not present in the managed type

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpa-2.0, criteria, criteria-api

I am selecting the following columns using multiselect of Criteria API

**Code snippet**

```
criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(MasterCat_.prodId),
joinProduct.get(ProductList_.prName).alias("productName"));

criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc
(root.get(mywrapperclass.getOrderBy()));
```

In above order by code snippet,I am passing `productName` from client.

and in constructor expression I have

```
public ProductListUtil(Long logId, String productName) {            
            this.logId = logId;
            productName = productName;
            }
```

The error I am getting is `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [productName] is not present in the managed type`.

How can I resolve this?

**Exception stacktrace**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The attribute [productName] is not present in the managed type [EntityTypeImpl@5185929:ProductList [ javaType: class test.entity.ProductList descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(test.entity.ProductList --> [DatabaseTable(PRODUCT_LISTS)]), mappings: 8]].
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metamodel.ManagedTypeImpl.getAttribute(ManagedTypeImpl.java:148)
>       at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.querydef.FromImpl.get(FromImpl.java:312)
>       at test.service.ProductListService.getProductListsList(ProductListService.java:129)
>       at test.service.ProductListService.getProductLists(ProductListService.java:101)
>       at test.service.ProductListService.getProductLists(ProductListService.java:94)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)

Comment: It is not saying there is no arg in the constructor ... it says there is no attribute in the class with that name. Is there?

Comment: @NeilStockton Spot on, thanks a ton for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not saying there is no arg in the constructor ... it says there is no attribute in the class with that name.